# Can Le be part of the data passed to PCSC SCardTransmit for a Case 4 command regardless of protocol?

Tags: pcsc

ISO/IEC 7816-3:2006 (12.1.2) defines the bytestring for a command to a Smart Card that sends data and is expected to produce some beyond a status word:

> A command APDU of case 4 consists of a header, a L<sub>C</sub> field, a data field and a L<sub>E</sub> field.

ISO/IEC 7816-4:2020 (5.2) is similar. I restrict to the short case (4S) where

- L<sub>C</sub> is a byte in 01<sub>H</sub>…FF<sub>H</sub> directly coding integer N<sub>C</sub> (the number of bytes in the data field, thus discounting the 4-byte header)
- L<sub>E</sub> is a byte in 01<sub>H</sub>…FF<sub>H</sub> directly coding integer N<sub>E</sub> (the number of bytes expected from the card in response when no error occurs, discounting status words), or 00<sub>H</sub> meaning *maximum* (or equivalently N<sub>E</sub>=256).

**In such case 4S, can L<sub>E</sub> be part of the data passed to PCSC [`SCardTransmit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winscard/nf-winscard-scardtransmit) regardless of the protocol?**

In other words, when passing such command to PCSC [`SCardTransmit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winscard/nf-winscard-scardtransmit), can we set `cbSendLength` to N<sub>C</sub>+6 regardless of the protocol?

I ask because I have a reproducible issue where including L<sub>E</sub> in a command (e.g. `00 A4 09 00  02  20 03  42` with `cbSendLength = 8` in a context where the card will actually return a status word `6A 82` and no data) causes `SCardTransmit` to fail. The value of the L<sub>E</sub> byte is immaterial. That's with T=0 cards from different manufacturers and applications, several readers of different models but all with the same manufacturer-recommended Windows driver (GemPcCCID 4.1.4.0 of 2016-08-08 signed 2018-07-26, [there](https://supportportal.gemalto.com/csm?id=kb_search&q=KB0015847)). The problem vanishes with Microsoft's default CCID WUDF driver, or if I set `cbSendLength` to one less (thus removing L<sub>E</sub>). I have so far found no other reader/driver configuration triggering *that* issue, so I'm tented to say that's a driver issue (or at least an issue of the combination of that driver and the PCSC service it's supposed to work with).

I'd like some specification that tells if it's legit to include the L<sub>E</sub> byte to `SCardTransmit`, and I'd prefer something not Windows-specific.

I understand that if somewhat the application knows that the protocol T=0 is used, it's easy to omit the L<sub>E</sub> byte from the initial `SCardTransmit`, and I see how L<sub>E</sub> can be handled subsequently when the card sends a 61xx status word. However some contactless Smart Card readers pretend to be T=0 when they really use the ISO/IEC 14443-4 protocol, and then the L<sub>E</sub> byte is useful in some cases, thus I don't want to use that option.

---

Addition: the [spec of ScardTransmit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winscard/nf-winscard-scardtransmit) has:

> For T=0, in the special case where no data is sent to the card and no data expected in return, this length (of the data passed to ScardTransmit) must reflect that the `bP3` member is not being sent; the length should be `sizeof(CmdBytes) - sizeof(BYTE)`(that is `4`, the length of the C-APDU).

Therefore, under in T=0, in cases 1, 2S, 3S, what's passed to ScardTransmit is the C-APDU, and in case 1 that differs from the C-TPDU. I'm asking if there is a reference settling about the imperative, in case 4S under T=0 specifically, to strip L<sub>E</sub> from a C-APDU (making it the C-TPDU) before passing it to ScardTransmit, similar to the above prescription to *not* make such conversion from C-APDU to C-TPDU in case 1 under T=0 (which ScardTransmit, the driver, or the reader will perform).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to ISO/IEC 7816-3:2006(E) command for T=0 protocol consists of CLA-INS-P1-P2-P3-Data, i.e. there is no any field behind data.

Clause 12.2.5 Case 4S is related to command-response pair transmission by T=0. It says:
The command APDU is mapped onto the command TPDU by cutting off the Le field.

So, no Le byte is allowed at the end of command int the case 4S.

Comment: I understand that the card is not supposed to receive Le in case 4S of protocol T=0. But the question asks if it's OK to pass it to SCardTransmit. After all, we should pass Le when using protocol T=1.

Comment: The fundamentals of T0 and T1 protocols are different despite from the viewpoint of SCardTransmit they are very similar. There is no way to accept Le byte by card using T=0. It's no OK to pass it.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69360304/903600), **it's not safe to pass a Case 4 command APDU to `SCardTransmit` complete with `Le` when under the T=0 protocol**. The question also asks where that's documented.

Such restriction is currently stated neither in [Microsoft's spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winscard/nf-winscard-scardtransmit) of `SCardTansmit`, nor in the [pscsclite spec](https://pcsclite.apdu.fr/api/group__API.html#ga9a2d77242a271310269065e64633ab99). However, `SCardTransmit` has historically been developed as an implementation (with different parameter passing but similar functionality) of `IFD_Transmit_to_ICC` specified by [PC/SC in Part 3, paragraph 4.3.2.1](http://pcscworkgroup.com/Download/Specifications/pcsc3_v2.01.09.pdf#page=45) (caution: possibly slow loading) and that states:

> Provisions for SCARD_PROTOCOL_T0 communication
> The `CommandData` needs to be formatted as an APDU as described in the ISO/IEC 7816-4. The following cases are supported:
>
> - Case 1: Command with no incoming or outgoing data byte: `CLA` `INS` `P1` `P2`
> - Case 2: Command with outgoing data bytes:  `CLA` `INS` `P1` `P2` `Le`
> - Case 3: Command with incoming data bytes: `CLA` `INS` `P1` `P2` `Lc` `[Data bytes]`
>
> Specific remarks:
>
> - Only the short format of `Lc` and `Le` is supported, i.e. one byte long.
> - An incoming order with no data byte « `CLA` `INS` `P1` `P2` » should be sent to the card as TPDU through a case 1 APDU.
> - A case 4 APDU cannot be used. It is the responsibility of the application or the service provider to generate a « get response » if they need it.

Hence when under the T=0 protocol, it's imprudent to pass `SCardTransmit` anything else than a Case 1, Case 2S, or Case 3S Command APDU.

If we pass a Case 4S Command APDU ( `CLA` `INS` `P1` `P2` `Lc` `[Lc Data bytes]` `Le`, with `Lc` in [`0x01`…`0xff]` ) that works fine with many drivers and readers. In my experience, both under Windows with Microsoft's Usbccid WUDF driver and many other vendor's drivers, and with pcsclite and it's companion libccid, the full C-APDU is passed to the reader, which filters out `Le` in the C-TPDU to the card, and everything is well. However there are exceptions, including the GemCCID 4.1.4 Windows driver, which performs no transfer and returns an error.